# Set of points of codimension greater than equal $m$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety. Consider the set of all points $A_m=\{x\in X: codim\,{x}\geq m\}$ for some integer $m$. Here codimension of a point is the codimension of its closure. Is this set $A_m$ closed? How do we prove this?

Comment: Far from it. Try $m=1$ and show that the closure of $A_1$ is all of $X$ (for $\dim X\geq 1$) or the same thing for $m=\dim X$.

Comment: @Mohan, I had this doubt because In Hartshorne's paper on reflexive sheaves, there is Corrollary 1.4, there he proves that -- a reflexive sheaf $F$  is locally free except along a closed set of codimension $\geq 3$. His proof is that If $x$ is a point of codimension 1 or 2, then the stalk $F_x$ is free. So I thought it meant $\{x\in X| codim\,x\leq 2\}$ is open and the complement is closed. Is it not the case?

Comment: You are reading it wrong. He says that the sheaf is free at codimension at most 2 points. But, he is not saying these are the only points where it is free. Whatever codimension is, the set of points where a coherent sheaf is free (say on an integral scheme) is always open, possibly empty.